# local development azure functions 'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'GetQueryNameValuePairs'

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am having trouble running an azure function locally that works in the portal.   I created a default C# Http trigger in Azure, then download the app content to run locally.

```
[5/22/18 9:03:21 PM] run.csx(8,23): error CS1061: 'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'GetQueryNameValuePairs' and no extension method 'GetQueryNameValuePairs' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[5/22/18 9:03:21 PM] run.csx(20,15): error CS1501: No overload for method 'CreateResponse' takes 2 arguments
```

The function works perfectly in the portal.

Comment: What's the version of Core Tools and Functions Runtime on your machine? (run `func` to see)

Comment: I figured this out after the post of course, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mikhail has said, it's caused by the wrong functions core tools(CLI) version. The code you download works with v1 CLI(.Net Framework) while v2(you may have installed) is on .NET Core.

To install required CLI, follow [CLI installation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#versions). If local OS(like MacOS) doesn't support v1 CLI we may turn to v2 CLI which can run cross-platform. With v2 CLI, v1 code created on portal can't be used, hence we need to [create functions locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#create-a-local-functions-project) or change portal function app runtime to ~2 then create and download again.

Note that before we change the runtime, function app should be empty because functions created before depend on different runtime and usually will become invalid after the change.

Comment: I figured this out after the post of course, thanks again.

Comment: it doesn't work for me (Mac).

npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for azure-functions-core-tools@1.0.12: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   darwin
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Comment: from docs:
Version 1.x: supports version 1.x of the runtime. This version is only supported on Windows computers and is installed from an npm package.

Comment: @RobinHalabicki Sorry that I forgot to mention the OS difference. Have updated my answer. Any further question, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

To give a specific example of code that does work, the below would work in Functions v2:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
       [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", 
        Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{

       int id;
       bool parsedId = int.TryParse(req.Query["id"], out id);
       ...
}
```